# How do I filter this ? Php

Tags: php, html

I got this code:

```
$yep = "(CA) Air China 887 Flight Status";
$search = '/^Status/';
preg_match($search, substr($yep,3), $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($match);
```

Why does my code ouputs this ?:

> Array ( ) (CA) Air China 887 Flight Status

I wanted to filter the word "Status" out of the string, how can I do this/fix this ?

**Edit:**

> The Solution:

```
$yep = "(CA) Air China 887 Flight Status";
$end = str_replace('Status', '', $yep)
```

> Or:

```
$yep = "(CA) Air China 887 Flight Status";
$end = preg_replace('/Status/', '', $yep);
```

Output will be:

> (CA) Air China 887 Flight

Comment: You want to remove `Status` and get the rest of string or need to match the `Status`?

Comment: Do you want to filter it like this? `$yep = preg_replace('/Status/', '', $yep);`

Comment: yea, but it´s not important which part of the string, just need to understand how it works...

Comment: @Thefourthbird, yes that´s whats the actual plan was

Comment: This code outputs `array(0) { }` since `^` matches beginning. it doesn't output `Array ( ) (CA) Air China 887 Flight Status

`

Comment: no it outputs it as in my question, that´s why i´m asking this question, i´m completely confused

Comment: Maybe `str_replace('Status', '', $yep)` is just as good.

Comment: Yep, that works perfect, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To replace the word `Status` in your string, you could use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

For the pattern you can use the word `Status`. (`^Status` would match it from the beginning of the string)

The replace that with an empty string ''

```
$yep = preg_replace('/Status/', '', $yep);
echo $yep;
```

That will give you:

> (CA) Air China 887 Flight

As you added in your question, this will solve your problem as well:

```
$yep = str_replace('Status', '', $yep);
```

Comment: whats the difference between str_replace and preg_replace?

Comment: From the docs: [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) replaces all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string, [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) performs a regular expression search and replace. In this case `str_replace` would also solve your problem.

Comment: by the way the first $yep should be changed to something else but everything else is right, Thanks to you too !